# XPath: Extract all URLs but those that contain a certain domain name

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to extract only a set of URL from a page, but my output contains some unwanted URLs that I would like to ignore.

Here is the expression used that extract all URL:

```
//div[contains(@id,'internal_trc_')]/div/a[2]/@href
```

I've tried this with no luck:

```
//div[contains(@id,'internal_trc_')]/div/a[2]/@href[not(contains(text(), 'domain.com'))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
@href[not(contains(text(), 'domain.com'))]
```

to

```
@href[not(contains(., 'domain.com'))]
```

because attributes have no text node children, but they do have string values.